# Как правильно перемещать объект после вращения в opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

У меня есть плоскость. Мне нужно эту плоскость повернуть относительно некоторой точки(Например ее центра). Затем мне нужно ее передвинуть. В чем проблема? Проблема в том, что после поворота плоскости ее оси поворачиваются и перемещение работает некорректно.
Что я делаю?

```
    void updateModelMatrix()
    {
        this->modelMatrix.setToIdentity();
        this->modelMatrix.translate(this->origin);
        this->modelMatrix.rotate(this->rotation.z(), QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, 1.f));
        this->modelMatrix.rotate(this->rotation.y(), QVector3D(0.f, 1.f, 0.f));
        this->modelMatrix.rotate(this->rotation.x(), QVector3D(1.f, 0.f, 0.f));
        this->modelMatrix.translate(this->position - this->origin);
    }
```

Вот проблемная операция

```
 this->modelMatrix.translate(this->position - this->origin);
```

Если я поверну плоскость по какой-то из осей(Например по Z на 90 градусов), то ее перемещение на мою желаемую позицию в сцене будет идти уже по осям повернутым на эти самые 90 градусов. Как мне повернуть плоскость но перемещать ее по глобальным осям?

Comment: Мне кажется, тут перепутано направление translate. В начале orign отодвигается в два раза дальше от начала кординат

Comment: Ну origin отодвигается да. У меня плоскость в буфере имеет точки LeftBoarder(0,0,0), RightBoarder(2, 2, 0)
Я ставлю origin(1, 1, 0) -> центр этой плоскости

Comment: Поиграйте с порядком операций. Вероятно сначала должно быть `translate(position)`, а после поворота `translate(-origin)`